# Implementing Custom GroupBy function in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm trying to implement a GroupBy function in such a way that it's generic and we don't end up having to keep adding properties every time the client wants something added/changed (yes, I know there's other options. Limited time/budget restrict the scope to this or hard-coding more properties, so I'm trying to opt for the better solution).

Currently I have the following;

```
<!-- language: lang-vb -->
Dim groupByColumns = New Dictionary(Of String, Boolean) From {
    {"Col1", True},
    {"Col2", False},
    ...
}

Dim groupedData = data.GroupBy(Function(r)
    Dim groupingResult = New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, Object))

    For Each column In groupByColumns
        Dim groupingValue As Object = Nothing
        If column.Value Then
            groupingValue = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(r).Item(grouping.Key).GetValue(r)
        End If
        groupingResult.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, Object)(column.Key, groupingValue))
    Next

    Return groupingResult
End Function)
```

If I then do an `OrderBy` or `Select` it seems to be returning an `IGrouping`, which is what I would expect, only the two data rows in the `data` object are still ungrouped, even though they are identical. I'm out of google-fu, can anybody please assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could combine the fields to group by into one key (probably a string) and then group by that value:

```
<!-- language: lang-vb -->
Dim groupedData2 = data.GroupBy(Function(r)
    Dim groupKey As New List(Of String)

    For Each column In groupByColumns
        If column.Value Then
            Dim p = r.GetType().GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(Function(p) p.Name = column.Key)
            Dim groupingValue = p?.GetValue(r)
            groupKey.Add(groupingValue)
        End If
    Next

    Return String.Join(",", groupKey)
End Function)
```